# What is the syntax error in this short ruby block?

Tags: ruby, syntax

What is the syntax error in this short ruby block?

```
def do_this (a,b,c)
    puts 1.to_s, 2.to_s,3.to_s
    if a == 4
        do_this (1,2,3)
    end
end
do_this (4,5,6)
```

I get errors on the fourth and seventh lines, where "`do_this`" is called.

The error is: `'unexpected ")", expecting "." or...' [...]`

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Code being submitted needs to run. Code with syntax errors are off-topic and will be closed. See #2 on https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Don't do `1.to_s, 2.to_s,3.to_s`. Output of a string or an integer results in the same thing on the screen, the visual representation of the values: `puts 1.to_s # >> 1` and `puts 1 # >> 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove spaces between method name and parentheses.

Comment: Why negative though? Does the downvoter has a better answer?

Comment: Possibly it's because your answer seems more like it'd be a comment, or because you misspelled "parentheses". Technically it's acceptable though very brief. Here's an up vote to maintain stasis.

Answer (score 1):

You need to avoid using spaces between the method call and the arguments in parenthesis:

```
def do_this (a,b,c)
  puts 1.to_s, 2.to_s,3.to_s
  if a == 4
    do_this(1,2,3)
  end
end
do_this(4,5,6)
```

Comment: Nay.. `puts 1.to_s, 2.to_s,3.to_s` is fine..won't throw error

Comment: My fault, although it changes a little bit, maybe is what he was trying to do (maybe not).

Comment: Maybe..maybe not.. but i agree, at first instance that seems to be an error but i tried running it and it works good..

Comment: I faced the same, but the error is just because of the method call, so, that's.